# Convert multidimensional array to a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My input is a multidimensional array and I want everything in the array to be in one string -

Input -

```
let input = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,,1]]
```

Expected Ouput

```
"123,132,321,312,213,231"
```

I have tried

```
input.join() // which gives me

"1,2,3,1,3,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,3,2,3,1"
```

And also I have tried

```
input.join('') // which gives me

"1,2,31,3,23,2,13,1,22,1,32,3,1"
```

I have also tried using a for loop for this

```
let input = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
let output = ''

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
 let result = input[i]
 output += result.toString()
}
```

Which returns

```
 "123132321312213231"
```

I can't seem to crack this... Any tips??

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've provided us with the correct code? The solution you provided works fine   `let input = [[123],[132],[321],[312],[213],[231]]; input.join();` outputs `'123,132,321,312,213,231'`

Comment: @RoMilton Apologies, there is meant to be a comma in the numbers array

Comment: You will want to map your inner array with an empty join.. eg.  `input.map(m => m.join('')).join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved simply using `.map()` with `.join('')` inside:

```js
const input = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,,1]];

const result = input.map(arr => arr.join('')).join();

console.log(result);
```

When you pass an empty string `''` into `.join()`, all elements are joined without any characters in between them.

Comment: Just stick another `join()` on the end..

Comment: @RoMilton thats almost there but my expected output is "123,132,321,312,213,231"

Comment: It's updated now @ubermo

Answer (score 0):

You almost there with your for loop

The other Solution from the User above me is in my opionion better

but here using your system you could do something like this:

```js
let input = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
let output = ''

// since we are working with an array why not use forEach, but you can also go with a normal for, or for of etc
input.forEach((array) => {
    // here we could another forEach for example
    array.forEach(number => { // adding all numbers inside the smaller array to one string
        output += number;
    })
    output += ','
})

output = output.slice(0, output.length - 1)
```

gives the output :

```js
"123,132,321,312,213,231"
```

Comment: Apologies, there is meant to be a comma in the numbers array

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is what you're looking for, but to join each array element without any separators requires an empty string `array.join("")`:

```js
    let input = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]

    let stringified2DArray = ""

    for (let i in input) {
      if (i == input.length-1) stringified2DArray += input[i].join("")
      else stringified2DArray += input[i].join("") + ','
    }

    console.log(stringified2DArray)
```

In the above example, we loop through each inner array, join each element and add comma afterward. If it's the last iteration in the loop, we exclude the comma to avoid a trailing comma.